# Eviction when using HQL queries

Tags: hazelcast

When I use a HQL statement like "delete from Setting where id=?" the 2nd level cache is not evicted from Hazelcast for the deleted entity.

Does anyone know about this issue? Is this a configuration problem?

Greetings,
Martin

Cache configuration:

```
<map name="default">
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <read-backup-data>false</read-backup-data>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>
</map>
```

Comment: I tried reproduce your case with a simple test(with hibernate 3 and LocalRegionCache) : https://github.com/kobalski/hazelcast-hibernate/blob/hibernate-sf-issue/hazelcast-hibernate3/src/test/java/com/hazelcast/hibernate/LocalRegionFactoryDefaultTest.java#L108 How do you verify cache eviction? Also there might be a configuration issue, can you give a little bit info about your config? There is not a know issue with HQL queries in HZ Second Level Cache impl.

Comment: have you tried deleting the entity with the session directly, like so: session.delete(ent). For this one I can verify that it is removed from the cache.

Comment: @İbrahimGürses I verified the invalid cache eviction by deleting the entity via the frontend and then loading it again. When manually evict the entity with currentSession().getSessionFactory().getCache().evictEntity(..) everything works as expected.

Comment: @u6f6o Yes, I tried it and it works as expected. But I do not know if I switch to session in every case and I am wondering why it does not work.

Comment: So, I created a unit test, which adds an entry (session.save(entity), closes the session, opens a new session, fetches the entity and checks afterwards that the entity is in the cache sessionFactory.getCache.containsEntity(Enttiy.class, entityID). Afterwards, I delete the entity using a HQL query, close the session and reload it. This time it's null and sessionFactory.getCache.containsEntity(Enttiy.class, entityID) returns false. Works for me.

Comment: @u6f6o Ok, then I have a look if I have a wrong configuration. Thx.

Comment: @MartinKrüger could you maybe provide a unit-test or code sample? Would be easier to reproduce.

Comment: @u6f6o I implemented a prototype with the same versions of Spring (4.0.5.RELEASE), Hibernate (4.2.5.FINAL) and Hazelcast (3.6.2) as in my project and have the same result as you. Everything works as expected.